# mousemove is not working in bootstrap collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap to show some assets in group like this.

```
Group 1
    - Item 1
    - Item 2
    - Item 3
Group 2
    - MItem 1
    - MItem 2
    - MItem 3
```

When Group 1 in expand mode then Item 1, Item 2 or Item 3 is moving with mouse properly. My code is:

```
var selector = $("li [data-code='df7668aac0afa3ee33549deef4c0fe7a']");

$('.row').mousemove(function(e){
    selector.show();                
    selector.css({'top': (e.pageY + 55), 'left': (e.pageX + 10), 'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '10'});
});
```

But when Group 1 in collapse mode then Item 1, Item 2 or Item 3 is not moving means hidden element is not moving.

Am I doning something wrong? Can anyone suggest me how to do this?